# How to continue a sound in Pygame?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I have a sound that I wish to play.

My code;

```
[...]
        if var_camera_flip == 1:
            if var_camera != 4:
                pygame.mixer.Channel(2).play(pygame.mixer.Sound(r'audio\camera\camera motor.mp3'), -1)
            else:
                pygame.mixer.Channel(2).stop()
        else:
            pygame.mixer.Channel(2).stop()
[...]
```

This code is in a subroutine that I call. What happens is that it restarts the sound each time it runs. What I want is that is the sound to continue playing until it is told not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not `stop` a sound, but `pause` it with [`pygame.mixer.Channel.pause`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel):

```py
pygame.mixer.Channel(2).pause()
```

Once a sound is paused it can be continued with [`pygame.mixer.unpause`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.unpause):

```py
pygame.mixer.Channel(2).unpause()
```